# Error running query Resources exceeded during query execution

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I run that query in GBQ I receive this error:

**Error running query**

> Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for
> query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.. at
> [1:1]

The code below is not developed by me so I have a hard time rewriting it. So would hear if you could help me get it running again.

```
execute immediate (select concat('create or replace table `ssmdw-208309.temp_piwik_and_ga.005_visitor_union` as ',query) from (select string_agg(CONCAT(' select substr(generate_uuid(),25,12) as rowid, ',columns,' from `piwik-272210.piwik.',table_name,'`'),'\nUnion all\n')  query FROM (
  SELECT
    table_column.table_name,
    STRING_AGG(CASE
        WHEN x.column_name IS NULL THEN CONCAT('null as ',table_column.column_name)
      ELSE
      table_column.column_name
    END
      ,', '
    ORDER BY
      table_column.column_name) columns
  FROM (
    SELECT
      tables.table_name,
      columns.column_name
    FROM (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT column_name
      FROM
        `piwik-272210.piwik.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` a where table_name like 'visitor_%') columns
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT table_name
      FROM
        `piwik-272210.piwik.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` b where table_name like 'visitor_%') tables
    ON
      (1=1)) table_column
  LEFT JOIN
    `piwik-272210.piwik.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` x
  ON
    (x.table_name = table_column.table_name
      AND x.column_name = table_column.column_name)
  GROUP BY
    1 )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid "order by" clause wherever it is possible. "Order by" tries to pull result in one node that in general causes this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input I have now removed the order by but I unfortunately still receive this error message --> 

Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.. at [1:1]

Comment: try eliminate intermediate too many subqueries. you can do it by storing intermediate result in some table. this can be achieved using stored procedure.

store result of below two queries in some tables:

`SELECT
        DISTINCT column_name
      FROM
        `piwik-272210.piwik.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` a where table_name like 'visitor_%') columns
   

`SELECT
        DISTINCT table_name
      FROM
        `piwik-272210.piwik.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` b where table_name like 'visitor_%') tables

then perform rest of operations.

Comment: Thanks for your input.
I have now implemented your solution, I unfortunately still receive the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Try this. then call the procedure.

```
create or replace procedure `dataset_name'.'procedure_name'()

BEGIN

create temp table TABL1 as (
SELECT  DISTINCT column_name FROM  `piwik-272210.piwik.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` a where table_name like 'visitor_%');
    

create temp table TABL2 as (
SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM `piwik-272210.piwik.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` b where table_name like 'visitor_%');

create temp table TABL3 as
SELECT tables.table_name, columns.column_name FROM (select column_name from TABL1 columns
                                                    FULL OUTER JOIN 
                                                    select table_name from TABL2 tables ON (1=1));

create or replace table dataset.TABL4 as
  SELECT   table_column.table_name, 
           STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN x.column_name IS NULL THEN CONCAT('null as ',table_column.column_name)  ELSE  table_column.column_name END) as columns
  FROM (
    SELECT table_name, column_name FROM TABL3
       ) table_column 
    left join `piwik-272210.piwik.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` x
    ON    (x.table_name = table_column.table_name AND x.column_name = table_column.column_name)
))

drop table TABL1 ;
drop table TABL2 ;
drop table TABL3;

END;
```